# Returning class to itself in python

Tags: python, class

Very simple question here, but I am new to python as an object oriented programming language. I am trying to write a class. Imagine it is organized as follows:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,a,b,runit=True):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        if runit:
            self.run_func()

    def run_func(self):
        self.c = self.a*self.b
        return
```

So as you can see the class is initialized with just `a` and `b`. It defaults to initialize `c` from those arguments, but it need not. Now let me illustrate three use cases that I think should behave the same, but are not:

```
# Use 1
test = myClass(5,2)
print(test.c)

# Use 2
test = myClass(5,2,runit=False)
test.run_func()
print(test.c)

# Use 3
test = myClass(5,2,runit=False).run_func()
print(test.c)
```

This returns the following:

```
10
10
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-cb854baa3a0c>", line 23, in <module>
    print(test.c)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Why can the instantiated class not be operated on immediately and pipe this result to `test` in one step? In my head, (1) and (2) are the same set of operations except one is broken into two steps and the other is done in one line.

And, more importantly, how can I fix this by editing my class to behave in the expected manner?

Comment: In "Use 3", you assign the return value of `.run_func()` (which is `None`) to `test`.  If you want to be able to chain methods together like that, you need `return self` instead.

Comment: In the third case, test is no longer an instance of your class. You are instantiating an anonymous myClass object, invoking that object's run_func method, and assigning the return value of run_func to test. The returned value is None, so test is None. None does not have an attribute 'c'. Sorry for the lack of syntax highlighting, I'm on my phone.

Comment: thanks everyone. I had done that originally, but something was off elsewhere in my code and I changed it to just `return`. I thought that having `self.c` be produced as a consequence of running the method would preserve the class, but this makes sense that it doesn't.

Comment: Note that having conditionnaly defined attributes is bad practice - at least for public attributes. `self.c` should still be defined (to a default or sentinel value) even if `run_func()` is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at `# Use 3` `myClass(5,2,runit=False).run_func()` returns `None`

to fix you could return `self`:

```
def run_func(self):
        self.c = self.a*self.b
        return self

test = myClass(5,2,runit=False).run_func()
print(test.c)
```

output:

```
10
```

or you should not set your flag `runit` to `False` and use:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,a,b,runit=True):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        if runit:
            self.run_func()

    def run_func(self):
        self.c = self.a*self.b

test = myClass(5,2)
print(test.c)
```

output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 2):

`run_func` should return `self`:

```py
    def run_func(self):
        self.c = self.a*self.b
        return self
```

stating `return` without a value following it, is the same as writing `return None`.
You get this exception because `None` has no attribute named `c`.

Answer (score 2):

In the 3rd case, `test` is assigned the return value of `run_func()`.  It has a bare `return` which returns `None`, so `test = None`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the method call in question:

```
test = myClass(5,2,runit=False).run_func()
```

Let's break that down. First, you construct an instance of `myClass` and then you call `run_func` on that instance. It's the return value of `run_func` that you assign to test and since `run_func` doesn't return anything `test` is `None` resulting in your error.

As another way to see this, try the following:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,a,b,runit=True):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        if runit:
            self.run_func()

    def run_func(self):
        self.c = self.a*self.b
        return 11

test = myClass(5,2,runit=False).run_func()
print(test) # will print 11
```

Comment: of course `myClass(5,2)` initializes `c`, it has a kwarg with default set to True

Comment: you're right; I missed that. Will remove that part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case 3

```
 test = myClass(5,2,runit=False).run_func()
 print(test.c)
```

`test` is not the object, but the return of the run_func(), which is null and indeed has no c attribute